# Загрузка контента ajax , переменная имя файла

Tags: php, ajax

Здраствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблемма? Скрипт так работает нормально но если пишу чтобы имя файла переменная то ajax не загружает текст из файла автоматически.

**Index.php**

```
<div id='result'></div>
    <div class='chatbody'>
      <form method="post" onsubmit="return lancerlechat();">
      <input type='text' name='idChat' id='idChat' value="<? echo $idChat; ?>" hidden/>
      <input type='text' name='chat' id='msgbox' placeholder="Пишите сообщение тут" />
      <input type='submit' name='send' id='send' class='btn btn-send' value='Отправить' />
      <input type='button' name='clear' class='btn btn-clear' id='clear' value='X' title="Удалить беседу" />
    </form>
    <script>
    function lancerlechat(){
        if($('#chat').val()=='' || $('#msgbox').val()==' ') return false;
        $.ajax({
          url:'chat.php',
          data:{msg:$('#msgbox').val(), idChat:$('#idChat').val(), send:true},
          method:'post',
          success:function(data){
            $('#result').html(data); 
            $('#msgbox').val(''); 
            document.getElementById('result').scrollTop=document.getElementById('result').scrollHeight; 
          }
        })
        return false;
    };
    setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url:'chat.php',
          data:{get:true},
          method:'post',
          success:function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
          }
      })
    },2000);
    </script>
    <div class='controlepanel'>
      <form method="post">
        <input type='text' class='input-user' placeholder="Ваше имя" name='username' />
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-user' value='Чат' />
      </form>
    </div>
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send']==true)
    {
      $idChat = $_POST['idChat'];
      
      $msgs = fopen("data.txt", "a");
      $data="<b>".$_SESSION['telegram'].':</b> '.$_POST['msg']."<br>";
      fwrite($msgs,$data);
      fclose($msgs);
      $msgs = fopen("data.txt", "r");
      echo fread($msgs,filesize("data.txt"));
      fclose($msgs);
    } else if(isset($_POST['get']) && $_POST['get']==true)
    {
      $msgs = fopen("data.txt", "r");
      echo fread($msgs,filesize("data.txt"));
      fclose($msgs);
    } else if(isset($_POST['clear']) && $_POST['clear']==true)
    {
      $msgs = fopen("data.txt", "w");
      $data="<b>".$_SESSION['telegram']."</b> удалил чат.<br>";
      fwrite($msgs,$data);
      fclose($msgs);
    }
?>
```

Ну вот если имя оставить data.txt или поменять на другое то все работает но как только имя файла это переменная то не работает нормально ajax. Создает файл txt открывает его в блок div можно писать сообщение и сохраняется в файл но только не подгружает автоматически файл в блок div result.

Помогите пожалуйста буду очень благодарен. Спасибо заранее

Comment: как подставляете переменную, покажите

Comment: Здраствуйте, по разному пробовал : `$msgs = fopen("$chatId.txt", "a");` `$msgs = fopen($chatId.".txt", "a");` а также пробовал переменную chatId конкотенировать с текстом .txt `$chatId = $chatId.".txt";` и все равно такой же результат